# Need help on Kafka to get data from web api GET Call

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As of now we are using curl and GET call  to  get data from outside using their ENDPOINT URL.

i'm planning to setup a new process and is there anyway to leverage kafka here instead of CURL.

unfortunately we dont have kafka confluent version.

Comment: You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't perform or accept HTTP calls.

You'd have to write some HTTP scraper, then combine this with a Kafka producer.

Note: You don't need Confluent Platform to just setup and run their REST proxy next to your existing brokers